# How to solve an equation $ x^3-y^2=20 $

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

X and y in this equation are both integer. One can see that pair x=6 and y=14, as well as x=6 and y=-14 are both solutions of this equation. It's easy to prove also that if x>6 entails $$ x=[y^{2/3}]+1$$
where as a [m] I gonna denominate an integer part of number m - max integer number which doesnt exceed m. For example, [8]=8, [1.6]=1, [-1.6]=-2. But I wonder if this goes long way and dont have any good idea about this equation. If your solution of this equation contains some interesting theory, links are appretiated.

Comment: Other than $(6,14)$, a computer search up to $x=5000000$ gave no further solutions in positive integers.  Not that this proves anything.

Answer (score 4):

The equation $$y^2 = x^3-20$$ is an example of a *Mordell equation* (cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordell_curve). You can find solutions for many $k$ in the range $-1000 \le k \le 1000$ at http://tnt.math.se.tmu.ac.jp/simath/MORDELL/.

Comment: The second link is not accessible for some reason.

Comment: Can you confirm that $(6,\pm 14)$ are the only solutions?

Comment: What you say in your second link is not true: there are a lot of values of $k$ for which there are not integer solution and even not rational not-zero solution at all. This fact is almost a characteristic of elliptic curves.

Comment: @Piquito: I should have been more specific/accurate: "where solutions are known and/or exist, you can find them at…" I’ve edited.

Answer (score 0):

$y^2 = x^3-20\tag{1}$
Using online Magma calculator as follows.

$E$:=EllipticCurve($[0, 0, 0, 0, -20]$);
IntegralPoints($E$);

It says that all integral points are $ [ (6 : -14 : 1) ] $.
Hence all integral points are $(x,y)=(6,\pm14).$

Comment: I'm sorry, but how does this online calculator prove that all integral points are (6,±14)? Only by not finding another?

Comment: @Specially, I guess this algorithm is based on elliptic logarithms method.
See Tzanakis's paper:
Solving elliptic diophantine equations
by estimating linear forms
in elliptic logarithms.
The case of quartic equations.

Comment: I found this paper: http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa75/aa7525.pdf Unfortunately, there is written that described methods are applicable to equations which look like a V
2 = Q(U) := aU^4 + bU^3 + cU^2 + dU + e^2, where a b c d and e are constants and a,e>0. Anyway, did Magma calculator provide you with a link to any theorem/paper like this?

Comment: How about Gebel's paper?: Computing integral points on elliptic curves.
https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiypfzF3orqAhWQd94KHbWjBC0QFjAAegQIBhAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmatwbn.icm.edu.pl%2Fksiazki%2Faa%2Faa68%2Faa6827.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1pEMRRfCI3pj7ushnER2C0

Comment: mathoverflow: intger points of elliptic curve
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/6676/integer-points-of-an-elliptic-curve?rq=1